# Qt internationalization and CMake: how to update *.ts and don't lose them

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

I'm having this `CMakeLists.txt` in directory with translation files (`*.ts`):

```
SET(TRANSLATIONS
    lang_de.ts
    lang_en.ts
)

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5LinguistTools)
QT5_ADD_TRANSLATION(QM_FILES ${TRANSLATIONS})
SET(QM_FILES ${QM_FILES} PARENT_SCOPE)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET (translations ALL DEPENDS ${QM_FILES})
```

It builds `*.qm` files from specified `*.ts`.

But I want to improve this and get two custom targets, which won't built automatically.
One for appending new strings from sources into `ts` files, and one for refreshing `ts`. The last one would update `ts` from sources and remove obsolete strings from `ts`.

I've tried to add this after lines above:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET (
    ts_append
    COMMAND QT5_CREATE_TRANSLATION(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/app ${TRANSLATIONS} OPTIONS -I ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET (
    ts_refresh
    COMMAND QT5_CREATE_TRANSLATION(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/app ${TRANSLATIONS} OPTIONS -no-obsolete -I ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
)
```

but it seems I can't use `QT5_CREATE_TRANSLATION` macro inside custom target, isn't it?

Maybe I'm on wrong way, how would you solve this problem: easy updating of `ts` and don't lose them after `make clean`?

Answer (score 2):

To solve the `make clean` problem, add a sub directory (`ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(translations)`) and add `SET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM 1)` to the contained CMakeLists.txt.
See [here](https://gist.github.com/02JanDal/70a39f2cc3d2002b3588) for an example of that.

For the second part of your question there are two possible ways to do it. Either use `FILE(WRITE <filename> "QT5_CREATE_TRANSLATION(QM_FILES ${SOURCE_DIR}/src/app ${TRANSLATIONS} OPTIONS -I ${SOURCE_DIR}/src)")` and then use `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DSOURCE_DIR=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -DTRANSLATIONS=${TRANSLATIONS} <filename>` in add_custom_target. I doubt there's a good way of retrieving the contents of QM_FILES though.
The second option is creating two additional sub directories, each with a QT5_CREATE_TRANSLATIONS and a ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET call.

Comment: SET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM TRUE) with a subdirectory does not work for me (using CMake 3.2.1): the link you've posted isn't available, so maybe you can elaborate how you made this work. If I specify SET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM TRUE) in the top-level file it is working though. I do want to have all other generated files deleted, so this is a workaround for me.

Comment: The file was since moved, I put it in a gist instead and updated the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jan! I had to delay work on this project and I have no configured dev environment to check your suggestion right now. I will mark answer as accepted as soon as I can try this

Comment: This solution will only work for Makefile generators, as per documentation at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM.html