# A proper workflow for CMake + Qt translation system

Tags: qt, cmake, workflow, translation

I recently moved my Qt project form qmake to CMake build system and now I'm trying to set up a translation system. I tried to use `qt5_create_translation` macro (documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html#qt5linguisttools-macros)) to update my *.ts files and generate *.qm files. By default the macro creates (or updates) *.ts files in the source directory and *.qm files in the build directory, which is pretty logical and convenient to use. The nature of underlying `lupdate` utility is such that *.ts files cannot be destroyed - they may be updated only. So I see my workflow as follows:

1. Add or modify source or UI files.
2. Rebuild the project: new translatable strings will be added to *.ts files.
3. Add actual translations to *.ts now or commit changes 'as is' in order to add the translations later.
4. As soon as translations are added to *.ts, rebuild the project to obtain the up-to-date *.qm files.

With this workflow *.ts files are almost always synchronized with source files and *.qm files are generated every time you build the project. But the ideology of CMake and/or Qt5 plugin for CMake follows another way. CMake rightly accounts *.ts files as build artifacts, so it generates a rule to delete them (from source tree (!)) on `make clean`. This behavior was at least [tw](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31860)[ice](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41736) registered as a bug, but maintainers seem to insist it's not a bug, but a feature.

I found an [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095800/qt-internationalization-and-cmake-how-to-update-ts-and-dont-lose-them) to add a subdirectory with translations and `CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM` on it, but these modifications break the build: adding *.qm file to executable target does not add the subdirectory to executable dependency list. So build build fails to find *.qm files and stops.

Adding custom CMake target and\or command invoking `lupdate` derogates all advantages of `Qt5LinguistTools` module and `qt5_create_translation` macro.

Adding a CMake option like [here](https://itk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Build_Qt4_Software) looks like an ugly workaround and does not keep the developer from loosing uncommitted translation by accidental invocation of `make clean` when `UPDATE_TRANSLATIONS` is turned on.

So what is the proper way to use `qt5_create_translation` macro with it's present-day behavior?

Answer (score -3):

without `do ADD_SUBDIRECTORY`,

I just add `SET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM TRUE)`

before calling

```
QT5_CREATE_TRANSLATION
```

Comment: @ymoreau This property is only valid for [Makefile generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_dir/CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM.html)